# coded ui test control becomes null after label changes value?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, coded-ui-tests

I am running coded ui tests on my application and i have encountered a problem:

I want to assert a label's text as it changes, but when this value changes my control becomes null (if i assert prior to changing the label's value it will be found and the assert will work).

Relevant code in my uimap (auto generated):

```
    public void assert_labelA()
    {
        #region Variable Declarations
        WinText uIAText = this.UIQuadraticSolverWindow.UIItem5Window.UIAText;
        #endregion

        Assert.AreEqual(this.assert_labelAExpectedValues.UIATextDisplayText, uIAText.DisplayText);
    }
...
[GeneratedCode("Coded UITest Builder", "10.0.40219.457")]
public class UIItem5Window : WinWindow
{

    public UIItem5Window(UITestControl searchLimitContainer) : 
            base(searchLimitContainer)
    {
        #region Search Criteria
        this.SearchProperties[WinWindow.PropertyNames.ControlName] = "labelA";
        this.WindowTitles.Add("Quadratic Solver");
        #endregion
    }

    #region Properties
    public WinText UIItem5Text
    {
        get
        {
            if ((this.mUIItem5Text == null))
            {
                this.mUIItem5Text = new WinText(this);
                #region Search Criteria
                this.mUIItem5Text.SearchProperties[WinText.PropertyNames.Name] = "5";
                this.mUIItem5Text.WindowTitles.Add("Quadratic Solver");
                #endregion
            }
            return this.mUIItem5Text;
        }
    }

    public WinText UIAText
    {
        get
        {
            if ((this.mUIAText == null))
            {
                this.mUIAText = new WinText(this);
                #region Search Criteria
                this.mUIAText.SearchProperties[WinText.PropertyNames.Name] = "A";
                this.mUIAText.WindowTitles.Add("Quadratic Solver");
                #endregion
            }
            return this.mUIAText;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Fields
    private WinText mUIItem5Text;

    private WinText mUIAText;
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Try calling UIAText.Find() before the assertion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this line was causing the problem:

```
    this.mUIItem5Text.SearchProperties[WinText.PropertyNames.Name] = "5";
```

it was a redundant criteria.